# I started receiving "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" on localhost, when it used to work fine

Tags: cors, .net-6.0

I know there are lots of questions related to this, but I am really struggling to find a solution to my problem.

I have control over the site and API. CORS has been set up to allow the specified origin (both http and https), and it has been working flawlessly for at least a year.

Recently it started showing error similar to below for all requests to the API. All these requests worked previously and I can't identify anything that has changed.

It seemed that Chromium based browsers stopped working first, while Firefox carried on working until it's latest update a couple of days ago.

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://localhost:44304/api/Dashboard/GetDailyItinerary' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3011' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

I am setting up CORS like this with the following domains:

```
var allowedOrigins = new List<string>();
Configuration.GetSection("AllowedOrigins").Bind(allowedOrigins);
services.AddCors(c => c.AddPolicy(name: _allowSpecificOrigins, policy => policy.WithOrigins(allowedOrigins.ToArray()).AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowCredentials()));


app.UseCors(_allowSpecificOrigins);
```

```
"AllowedOrigins": [
  "http://localhost:3011",
  "https://localhost:3011",
  "http://localhost:3013",
  "https://localhost:3013"
]
```

I have tried looking through the change history to see if anything has broken it, but `Startup.cs` has barely been touched in the last year.
The API is run as https, and running the front end as http or https gets the same response.

Once the site is deployed to our server, the requests works fine and there are no CORS issues, though it is configured with different domains. This seems to be an issue specifically with localhost, and due to the browsers getting the issue at different times I suspect some sort of browser policy or regulation has changed.

Any suggestions or ideas I could try? Does any body know of any browser breaking changes that might have triggered this?

**Things I have tried**

1. `.AllowAnyOrigin()` has the same result
2. Using a custom url in my host file has the same result
   [image]
3. Using HTTPS on the front end makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

@Edit: What is `cpl.local:3011` ? It is different from the typical `localhost` base address. Anyway, you should add it to origins as I do, not as yours.

I don't well understand your configuration seeming gobbledygook a tad.

Using cors should be before `UseAuthorization()` as the order of middleware is too important.

```
...
...

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
```

When adding services, add the following.

```
string[] allowedOrigins = new[]{
"http://localhost:3011",
"https://localhost:3011",
"http://localhost:3013",
"https://localhost:3013",
"https://cpl.local:3011",
"http://cpl.local:3011",
};

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
                        {
                            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", 
                            corsPolicyBuilder => corsPolicyBuilder
                                                .AllowAnyHeader()
                                                .AllowAnyMethod()
                                                .WithOrigins(allowedOrigins));
                        });
```